# Issues with catching requests exceptions

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests

I'm creating delete request to webserver and trying to catch the exceptions like below:

```
 try:
    response = req.delete(path, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(config.user(), config.password()), params=params, headers=headers, verify=True)
except requests.HTTPError as he:
    raise SystemExit(he)
except requests.ConnectionError as ce:
    raise SystemExit(ce)
except requests.URLRequired as ue:
    raise SystemExit(ue)
except requests.Timeout as te:
    raise SystemExit(te)
except requests.RequestException as err:
    print('Undefined error: ', err)

print(response.status_code)
```

But delete is not processed and `response.status_code` prints `400`, but error handling does not work. Any ideas why the error handling is not working there?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to catch http errors (e.g. 401 Unauthorized) to raise exceptions, you need to call Response.raise_for_status. That will raise an HTTPError, if the response was an http error.

```
try:
    response = req.delete(path, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(config.user(), config.password()), params=params, headers=headers, verify=True)
except requests.HTTPError as he:
    raise SystemExit(he)
```